# How to show symfony roles

Tags: symfony

I'm working with symfony 2.3. How I can show the user roles without (ROLE_). I want to change the view, but in the database are intact.

When I display the roles in the view I have this

- ROLE_ADMIN
- ROLE_CONSULTOR

and I want

- Admin
- Consultor

Comment: Generally speaking, those are identifiers and are for internal representation.     Common practice is to map identifiers to human readable values, or implement Groups that have associated roles.

Answer (score 0):

Role Entities just need to implement the RoleInterface.  You can add your own custom fields such as the names you want.

http://api.symfony.com/2.3/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Role/RoleInterface.html

Answer (score 0):

Not clear what you want to achieve, but if there are few roles, may be 2-3, (e.g. ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_CONSULTOR, ROLE_USER), just define a method which receives the system role, returns the human readable one. May be like this:

```
public function convertToHumanreadable($role)
{
    $return = null;
    switch ($role) {
        case 'ROLE_ADMIN':
            $return = 'Admin';
        break;

        ...
    }

    return $return;
}
```

Or even like this:

```
public function convertToHumanreadable($role)
{
    $roleParts = explode('_', $role)

    return ucfirst(strtolower($roleParts[1]));
}
```

Or you can create your own role entity by implementing the `RoleInterface` as @DerickF mentioned.